# Compiling COBOL program on mac yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

While I'm running my COBOL code:

```
$ cobc hello.cob
```

I'm getting an error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-R/opt/local/lib'
```

(Today,) I installed GnuCOBOL as root with

```
$ port selfupdate
$ port install open-cobol
```

Comment: The GnuCOBOL project on SourceForget.Net provides assistance for this in a format allowing more to/fro of information. I'd suggest you ask there.

Comment: It looks like the installation wasn't done properly, or there are some prerequisites not being met for the installation.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this has to do with Apple aliasing gcc to clang, but clang isn't a drop-in replacement for gcc yet.  So it breaks on a few things.  There is no simple way to fix this.  If you type gcc you get clang.

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I'm not going to list all the details here, (and I know links are frowned on here on SO, but the entire thread will need to be read to get to grips with this problem.  (Scripts are involved that strip some arguments out).

There is very little the GnuCOBOL compiler authors can do about this.  The Mac clang is actually defining GNUC as well, so the compiler code that tests for gcc features is currently ineffective, clang reporting itself as gcc.  Under a real gcc, the run-path setting in the ELF output is necessary, so -R can't just be yanked out.  I see this as slightly dirty pool on Apple's part, but, it is their system, to wall off as they see fit.

http://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/help/thread/e1b4af35/

Changes to GnuCOBOL will try and workaround the issue, but that may take a while to get out into the wild.